# c7200 IOS 15.x-x NAT/PAT issue

Tags: cisco, nat, ios

My problem may be just finger trouble, but after fighting with this for a day on what should have taken 5mins, I am getting fustrated. I am not Cisco Certified at any level, just a fair amount of experience. So I am asking for help before i take a big hammer to this router :)

This equipment is off contract, No TAC suport contract either.
My question is below the setup details.

Hardware and physical configuration (these are actual devices, not GNS3):
Cisco 7206VXR with NPE-G1 256MB/64MB (more ram and flash has been ordered), No I/O controller (not needed with G-series NPE) only one PA-2FE-TX card installed in slot1, All other slots are "open" (blanking plates installed for cooling reasons)
NPE-G1 has 3 gigabit layer 3 interfaces, PA-2FE has 2 fast ethernet layer 3 interfaces.

gi0/1 is connected to another router, this other router has minimal config (only has an IP 4.4.4.4/16 on the connected interface) on it to provide a remote connection to connect to.
fa1/0 is connected to a laptop. the laptop ip is statically set to 192.168.1.20/24

software I am trying to use:
rommon version 12.2(24)T
I am using c7200-kboot-151-4.m2 for the boot loader
IOS version c7200-adventerprisek9-mz.152-4.m6

to ensure no other config has lingered, I formatted the flash: before loading the new IOS and cleared all config files from nvram:

with a clean (non-existing) startup-config I enter these commands as shown:

```
en
conf t
int gi0/1
ip add 2.2.2.2 255.255.0.0
ip nat outside
no shut
exit
int fa1/0
ip add 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
no shut
exit
ip access-list standard 1
permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
exit
ip nat inside source list 1 int gi0/1 overload
end
```

IOS adds 'ip virtual-reassembly in' to both interfaces automatically. 
ip cef is enabled by default.

This is all I have ever had to do, works in adventerprisek9-mz.151-4.M4 on c3800 equipment.
I have tried setting up a nat pool with only my external IP in it and also tried using a route-map. none have worked so far.

I have also tried using only the gigabit interfaces and still the same results.

I can ping from the 7206 to the laptop and the other router. these each can ping the 7206, but I get no nat translations no matter what I do. I have been using telnet to force a translation.

All of these IOS's require (according to Cisco) 512MB/64MB, I have 256MB/64MB and they load without issues (no warnings) I have 1GB ram and 512MB flash on the way, but since the 124.24 ios works I dont think it is a ram issue.

I have down graded to c7200-kboot-mz.151-4.m2 and c7200-adventerprisek9-mz.151-4.m2  This did not work either.
Another downgrade to c7200-kboot-mz.124-24.t3 and c7200-adventerprisek9-mz.124-24.t3 ( just above the lowest IOS usable) just to confirm and this IOS works with my config.

My question is: What am I doing wrong? I have looked at the cisco documentation and at other guides, but I can not make this work with the IOS I need.

I need IOS 15.1 for some other features that are needed in my final setup.

By the way, voting for the hammer requires said voter to put up the replacement cash. ;)

Comment: Can you please briefly summarize your problem at the top of your post, and maybe provide a more descriptive title?  Your post is long and it's hard to find exactly what the problem is without reading every word.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, There is a subtle incompatibility with the kboot image and the full IOS image. Simply add a boot bootldr bootflash:ignore statement to your config (must be done in an editor if you dont want the hassle of creating a virtual file) then only have one IOS image in flash, the full image. The router boots and works as expected with a small bonus of reduced boot times.